Excel split text keeping font color
I'm trying to separate text within cells into different cells keeping the font color on each letter.
Ex.
|Holy Smith (Blue), Jack Thompson (Green), Adam Mills (Red)|
into |Holy Smith (Blue)|Jack Thompson (Green)|Adam Mills (Red)|
I need all cells in the same row as it's a long list.
Any help very appreciated!
I found the below on a different question but I need it to cut cells at every ", " instead of " ". Also the code is transposing the results and I need them on the same row.
Sub splitWithColor()
    Dim vStr As Variant, v
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Note we are working with "active sheet"
'you should have stronger definitions in final product
Set rSrc = Range("A1")
Set rRes = Range("A3")

vStr = Split(rSrc.Value2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vStr) + 1)
rRes.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vStr)
I = 0
J = 1
For Each v In vStr
    rRes.Offset(I)(1).Font.Color = rSrc.Characters(J, 1).Font.Color
    I = I + 1
    J = J + Len(v) + 1
Next v

End Sub```


As BigBen wrote, you can provide the delimiter as 2nd parameter to the split function, so in your case, this would be ",".
The following routine is flexible, you can provide different delimiters and specify if you want to write the words horizontal or vertical. It also copies the font color character by character so that a word that contains multiple colors will look the same after copying. If you want, you can also copy other properties (size, bold...), but note that this can slow down the code.
I have added the lTrim-function to get rid of leading blanks, this makes it a bit tricky to get the correct position in the original cell text, I have introduced the variable blankCount for that.
Sub SplitFormattedText(sourceCell As Range, destcell As Range, Optional delimiter As String = ",", Optional horizontal As Boolean = True)
    Dim words() As String
    words = Split(sourceCell, delimiter)
    
    Dim rowOffset As Long, colOffset As Long
    rowOffset = 0
    colOffset = 0
    
    Dim wordStartPos As Long
    wordStartPos = 0
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
        Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = destcell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset)
        Dim word As String
        word = LTrim(words(i))
        Dim blankCount As Long
        blankCount = Len(words(i)) - Len(word)  ' Number of leading blanks
        
        cell.Value = word    ' Write the (trimmed) word into cell
        
        ' Now copy the formatting character by character from the source cell
        Dim chrIndex As Long
        For chrIndex = 1 To Len(words(i))
            Dim sourceChrIndex As Long
            sourceChrIndex = wordStartPos + chrIndex + blankCount
            cell.Characters(chrIndex, 1).Font.Color = sourceCell.Characters(sourceChrIndex, 1).Font.Color
            'cell.Characters(chrIndex, 1).Font.Size = sourceCell.Characters(sourceChrIndex, 1).Font.Size
            'cell.Characters(chrIndex, 1).Font.Name = sourceCell.Characters(sourceChrIndex, 1).Font.Name
            'cell.Characters(chrIndex, 1).Font.Bold = sourceCell.Characters(sourceChrIndex, 1).Font.Bold
            'cell.Characters(chrIndex, 1).Font.Italic = sourceCell.Characters(sourceChrIndex, 1).Font.Italic
        Next chrIndex
        wordStartPos = wordStartPos + Len(words(i)) + Len(delimiter)
        ' increment offset so next word is written to next cell
        If horizontal Then colOffset = colOffset + 1 Else rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
    Next i
End Sub

Do a Test:
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        SplitFormattedText .Range("A1"), .Range("B1"), ",", True
        SplitFormattedText .Range("A1"), .Range("A2"), ",", False
    End With
End Sub

Cells B1:D1 are filled with the first call to the routine, A2:A4 with the second call:


If the color change coincides with the commas separating the words, then the following modification will suffice:
Sub splitWithColor()
    Dim vStr As Variant, v
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Note we are working with "active sheet"
'you should have stronger definitions in final product
    Set rSrc = Range("A1")
    Set rRes = Range("A3")

    vStr = Split(rSrc.Value2, ", ")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rRes = rRes.Resize(1, UBound(vStr) + 1)
    rRes.Value = vStr
    I = 1
    J = 1
    For Each v In vStr
        rRes(I).Font.Color = rSrc.Characters(J, 1).Font.Color
        I = I + 1
        J = J + Len(v) + 2
    Next v

End Sub


